# Login to my Windows Phone 7 app using Facebook user

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app with Azure. I want let users use their facebook account to login but I need to store an ID to identify that user.

I want to store in SQL Azure, the user's stats and I don't know if I can use there Facebook Login.

How do I identify a user that has logged in with a Facebook account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), I've found this:

*"Every object in the social graph has a unique ID"*

This is what I was looking an Unique ID to identify users logged using Facebook Login.